# Images are not aligned

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, image-size

I have two post's next to each other on one of my pages. I have them take up the full width of the page. Although I got this to work, on the right the thumbnail has a small gap under it. This only happens on safari not on chrome. I have researched and found this gap could happen if you don't have you img tags on the same line. However, I am not using ing tags, I'm calling elements from wordpress. Does anyone have any other solutions on how to fix this? Can it be done through css? Thanks in advance.

safari, see how the bottom of the pictures don't line up
[image]

chrome, how I want it to look - bottom of pictures line up
[image]

fiddle with img tags instead of php - https://jsfiddle.net/v90pug4o/
although this is not completely similar to my problem I thought I would provide it in img tags since my code is in php. There is still a gap in the fiddle (its on the right side) its very noticeable when you compare it to this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5bp0a3rf/ - where I put the img tags on the same line. However unfortunately I am not able to do this with my code since it's php. So thats why I was wondering if there are any other options?

```html
<div class="food-featured-posts">

  <div class="food-featured-posts-first">
    <?php query_posts( 'p=185'); while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
  </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>


  <div class="food-featured-posts-second">
    <?php query_posts( 'p=173'); while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
```

css

```html
.food-featured-posts-first img {
  width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
.food-featured-posts-second img {
  width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
.food-featured-posts-first  {
  width: 50%;

}
.food-featured-posts-second  {
  width: 50%;

}
.food-featured-posts {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post HTML with valid img tags that we can use to replicate your images, instead of posting PHP?

Comment: Posted a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/v90pug4o/

Comment: Your fiddle aligns the images the same on both Safari and Chrome for me. Can you try clearing your cache on Safari, if you haven't already?

Comment: @AnishSana they're off by 1px. What's weird is Safari doesn't seem to allow you to break the aspect ratio of the image. Like it won't allow you to force the image to be 100% width and 50% width, or vice versa... I'm stumped, haven't run into this before. https://jsfiddle.net/v90pug4o/2/

Comment: @MichaelCoker I've tried removing the `<div>` tags for each of the images and using `id`s instead of `class`es. The images line up perfectly in Safari but they're vertical in Chrome. I'm guessing this has to do with the flex property being used? - https://jsfiddle.net/qjx3t3qs/1/

Comment: Is the height of <div class="food-featured-posts"> specified in css or inherited via another css rule?

Comment: I never specified the height of the class food-featured-posts. So it must be inherited?